# Moving page file - should i keep "some" on the primary drive?

Tags: memory, ssd, pagefile

I run win10 with 16GB RAM (thinking of getting 32GB soon).

My operating system is on a 512GB SSD.

I read that I may benefit by moving the pagefile to a non system drive and since I have 2 more SSDs I want to know if it is advisable to move the page file to a non system (SSD) drive?

I know how to do that, however, I also read that even if you move the pagefile to a non system drive it is still advisable to keep "some" on the system drive.

Is this true? If moving the page file to another SSD advisable, do I need to still keep "some" on the primary drive and if yes how much and how do I  that?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't see a benefit with SSDs. With HDDs I could see why you'd do that but with an SSD you're not running into the same issues. Where did you read about that split? What was the argument for it?

Comment: Imagine that you move pagefile to non-system drive, and it is not available during boot by some reason. How do you think, does OS will boot?

Comment: @Seth I read it in various places,. The argument was that R/W operation will not be done on the same drive which can improve performance.
Do you think I should not move it?

Comment: @Akina by using RAM. Unless you have a very restricted system (which is not the case with 16 GB) you shouldn't need the pagefile during boot.

Comment: @dandan it depends on what you do. You can move it if you want to. The argument you've brought up is right for moving it in the first place but not for the split between system and non system drive. The R/W is much more of a problem for mechanical discs. With SSDs this shouldn't be an issue with regular use. In the end what you actually do with your system is a major matter for that decision.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep at least some small amount of page file on your system for a crash dump. How much depends on the setting for your system but chances are you as a home user it is set to "small" in which case it does not need to be a large page file at all.

From [How to determine the appropriate page file size for 64-bit versions of Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/determine-appropriate-page-file-size)

```
System crash dump setting  | Minimum page file size requirement
Small memory dump (256 KB) | 1 MB
Kernel memory dump         | Depends on kernel virtual memory usage
Complete memory dump       | 1 x RAM plus 257 MB*
Automatic memory dump      | Depends on kernel virtual memory usage. For details, see Automatic memory dump.
```

Whether it is *worth* moving depends on the types of SSD. There would be little benefit in moving from an NVME SSD to a SATA SSD, due to SATA being slower, but the other direction *could* be worthwhile.

If they are both the same type then the benefit is going to be marginal and depend on how heavily one drive is used and the type of work you do. Large video editing with page file on the same drive might result in some bus contention in low memory situations, so you'd want the page file on to the other drive from that work.

Other than that there is little benefit to moving it. SSDs are much less prone to the problems of seek times that make hard drives painful to use when they are paging data in and out.

Comment: Yes my page file is on an SSD.
I wanted to know if it would be wise to move it to a different SSD. The answer I got so far is No - keep it as it is, on the primary C drive.

Comment: Moving to another SSD would possibly be a marginal benefit at best, and there are some tradeoffs either way. Are both SSDs SATA or NVME or is there a mix? Sorry, I misread and thought you were putting it on a hard drive.

Comment: Both are SSDs connected to SATA6 bus.
I currently have 16GB RAM and I am thinking of upgrading to 32GB.
I usually notice that the pagefile is 16-17GB.

Comment: @dandan it mostly depends on your use case then. Benefits are going to be marginal and depend on your workload and which drive is used at the time. I have edited.

Comment: My page file is always allocated to 16384, even right after reboot.
Is this normal? I read that it should not always occupy a size equivalent to my RAM, If I upgrade to 32GB it will occupy 32GB!

Comment: @dandan I have 32GB and my page-file is set to automatic. My page file is currently 4864MB so slightly shy of 5GB. You might want to clear it by setting it to a small size (or off), rebooting, then setting it back to "automatic". It won't reset size after every reboot [unless you tell windows to delete it every time](https://www.google.com/search?&q=clear+page+file+windows+10), which would be a waste of SSD writes as it has to refill every boot. It will grow to a maximum *needed*.

Comment: I set the size to 3000MB, restarted, reset to automatic, restarted and it went back to  16384MB.
It does however shows, on the Virtual Memory settings, under system properties:
Min allowed: 16MB, Recommended 2934, Currently allocated 16384.
So why is it using so much? is this normal?

Comment: @dandan Doesn't sound normal. What setting do you have under the "Startup and recovery" settings as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/koKJb.png I believe that "Complete memory dump" instead of "automatic", "small" or any of the others might cause what you are seeing. For me it is automatic and results in a smaller page file.

Comment: Yes that is what i was using and i changed it now to automatic

Comment: I did the same think you suggested before after setting this to small memory dump (256k).
Set to "no page file", restarted, reset to automatic, restarted.
Page file was reduced by only 3GB to 13312.
Anything else i can check/set to make it (normally) smaller?

Comment: Setting the debug information to automatic, instead of small did not make any change - it is still 13312